# "ImportError: cannot import name _LIB ", mxnet Error

Tags: mxnet

I'm using conda environment with python 2.7.18 and a couple of neccessary packages installed for running a pre-written code. While executing the code, I face this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/hgfs/T4/a-link/code/face_model.py", line 11, in <module>
    import mxnet as mx
  File "/home/z/v_env/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .context import Context, current_context, cpu, gpu, cpu_pinned
  File "/home/z/v_env/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/context.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .base import classproperty, with_metaclass, _MXClassPropertyMetaClass
  File "/home/z/v_env/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    import numpy as _np
  File "/home/z/v_env/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/numpy/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/home/z/v_env/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/numpy/random.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..ndarray import numpy as _mx_nd_np
  File "/home/z/v_env/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/ndarray/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import _internal, contrib, linalg, op, random, sparse, utils, image, ndarray, numpy
  File "/home/z/v_env/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/ndarray/_internal.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .._ctypes.ndarray import NDArrayBase, CachedOp
  File "/home/z/v_env/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mxnet/_ctypes/ndarray.py", line 25, in <module>
    from ..base import _LIB
ImportError: cannot import name _LIB
```

I have mxnet-1.8.0 installed and working on Ubuntu 20.04. The code will train a network and I want to use CPU and no GPUs.

Here is some part of 'base.py' which error refers to:

```
def _load_lib():
    """Load library by searching possible path."""
    lib_path = libinfo.find_lib_path()
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
    # DMatrix functions
    lib.MXGetLastError.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
    return lib


# version number
__version__ = libinfo.__version__
# library instance of mxnet
_LIB = _load_lib()

...
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.